# TextRange.Load() в другом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, flowdocument

Пишу WPF приложение. Есть кнопка, задача которой взять из MySQL таблицы массив байтов (который на деле представляет из себя содержание TextRange) и загрузить его в FlowDocument. Всегда это делал подобным образом:

```
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(bytesFromDB)
            {
                TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
                    flowDoc.ContentStart,
                    flowDoc.ContentEnd);
                textRange.Load(mem, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
            }
```

*(В базу данных этот массив байтов записывается аналогичным образом. Записываю в MemoryStream в формате XamlPackage из TextRange'a, выполняю метод ToArray() и отправляю в базу данных этот массив. Но это всё не важно, перейду к самой проблеме.)*

Всё прекрасно работало, пока я не решил код выше переместить в отдельный поток. Ибо приложение замораживается, если массив байтов большой.

В случае отдельного потока, он просто выдает ошибку, что bytesFromDB содержит некорректную информацию для формата XamlPackage, при выполнении:

```
textRange.Load(mem, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
```

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Нераспознанная структура в формате данных
>   "XamlPackage".

Т.е. в основном потоке он преобразует **тот же самый массив байтов** в XamlPackage нормально, а в запуске отдельного потока (Пробовал и через Thread, Task и BackgroundWorker) он выдает ошибку, что неверный формат.

Немного попробовав разные способы, понял, что он ругается только в том случае, если TextRange содержит изображение (в FlowDocument), даже изображение в размере 1 пикселя :D Хотя опять же, в основном потоке, textRange с изображенем хорошо загружается в MemoryStream.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл эту тему, наткнувшись на такую же проблему. Только у меня она возникла при разборе RTF-документа с картинкой в основном потоке консольного приложения. Решение нашёл быстро - оказывается, достаточно пометить `Main` атрибутом *[STAThread]*.
В общем, логично - для работоспособности WPF и всего, что с ним связано, нужен STA-поток. Соответственно, прежде чем запускать поток, вызовете `thread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`

Answer (score 1):

(*См. обновление в конце.*)

---

Прямая загрузка большого документа не очень хороша, т. к. блокирует UI-поток. Простой код

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var doc = new FlowDocument();
var tr = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\CSharp Language Specification.rtf"))
    tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
Viewer.Document = doc;
sw.Stop();
Status.Text = "Finished in " + sw.Elapsed;
```

грузил на моей машине спецификацию C# в качестве тестового документа около 10 секунд, всё это время UI был заморожен, что, разумеется, недопустимо. (Ещё 8 секунд занимала фоновая разбивка на страницы.)

Имеет смысл грузить страницу в другом формате. Например, загрузка из формата XAML того же документа на моей машине происходит мгновенно. Но сама конвертация в этот формат получается намного дольше.

Вот такой код:

```
try
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Viewer.Document = null;
    Status.Text = "Loading...";
    Progress<string> p = new Progress<string>(s => Status.Text = s);
    var xaml = await Task.Run(
        () => LoadAsXamlInBackground(@"D:\CSharp Language Specification.rtf", p));
    Status.Text = "Rendering...";
    var doc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
    Viewer.Document = doc;
    sw.Stop();
    Status.Text = "Finished in " + sw.Elapsed;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Status.Text = "Failed: " + ex.ToString();
}

// ...
MemoryStream LoadAsXamlInBackground(string filename, IProgress<string> progress)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var doc = new FlowDocument();
    var tr = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    progress.Report("Loaded, converting...");
    XamlWriter.Save(doc, ms);
    progress.Report("Converted...");
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

не приводил к зависанию UI вовсе, но бежал существенно дольше. Код `tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf)` бежал всё те же 10 секунд, а вот `XamlWriter.Save(doc, ms);` заняло целых 80. Остальной под пробежал практически мгновенно.

---

Перечитал вопрос, у вас уже сериализированный текст. Если так, всё проще. Вы можете

1. Сохранить код в базу в таком виде, как он сохраняется в `MemoryStream` в методе `LoadAsXamlInBackground`. Этот метод медленный, но вам всё равно, т. к. это используется для *создания*, а не чтения.
2. В читающем коде грузить `MemoryStream` из базы в фоновом потоке, и читать `XamlReader`'ом.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Пишу WPF приложение. 
> Всё прекрасно работало, пока я не решил код выше переместить в отдельный поток.
```

если данные из отдельного потока надо выводить в контролы (созданы в UI-потоке), то надо использовать Dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем запускать поток, нужно вызвать `TrySetApartmentState (ApartmentState.STA)`.

Пример кода:

```
Thread th = new Thread (delegate () { 
    load (); 
});
th.TrySetApartmentState (ApartmentState.STA);
th.Start ();
```

Где `load()` функция в которой идет загрузка в `TextRange`.

Без `th.TrySetApartmentState (ApartmentState.STA)` вылетает `Exception`.

Comment: Если Вы считаете какой то ответ верным - отметьте его как полезный. Если есть замечания к ответу - напишите коментарий. Если есть свой вариант ответа - милости просим - напишите развернутый ответ.

Comment: @V.March, ну он код дописал к тому ответу.

Comment: Не могу отмечать ответ как полезный или писать замечания - не хватает репутации.