# Зависает интерфейс до отображения RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Разрабатываю простенькое приложение UWP, отображающее содержание rtf документа в RichEditBox. На пк всё загружается моментально, а вот на Windows 10 Mobile до отображения контента проходит 5-10 секунд. В это время прочие элементы управления не отвечают. Как только RichEditBox заканчивает отрисовку текста, так всё приходит в норму.
 Вот код RichEditBox.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Rich = new RichEditBox();
     Rich.IsReadOnly = true;
     Rich.IsSpellCheckEnabled = false;
     Rich.IsTextPredictionEnabled = false;
     Rich.IsHitTestVisible = false;
     Rich.BorderThickness = BorderThickness;


    vile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + Convert.ToString(set) + ".rtf"));
     randAccStream = await vile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
     Rich.Document.LoadFromStream(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, randAccStream);
     Rich.FontFamily = new FontFamily("/Assets/AcademyOSTT.ttf#AcademyOSTT");
     await Task.Delay(5);
     MyStackPanel.Children.Add(Rich);
}
```

Зависание происходит из-за последней строчки. Пока отрисовывается Rich, все остальные элементы остаются не доступными.

Как мне решить данную проблему? Мне нужно, чтобы прочие элементы управления оставались в рабочем состоянии на время загрузки Rich. Спасибо.

Comment: Наверное, вам поможет это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503181/10105. Дубликат?

Answer (score 1):

Зависание происходит из-за того, что вы захватываете поток UI, что бы забросить туда свой RichTextBox. Не знаком с UWP, но, подозреваю, просто обновление на мобильных приложениях происходит не так часто /с большими тормозами.
Что бы я попробовал в вашем случае.

1. Не добавлять RichTextBox, а изначально его там вставить и пусть живет в дереве. Если надо конвертерами видимость править.
2. Связь с текстом будет на Binding-е, если он тяжёл, то можно распилить, создав свой ITextFormatter который будет потихоньку асинхронно подгружать текст.